# Expand width of R code chunks within an R presentation

Tags: css, r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I am looking for a solution to expand the width of code chunks in an markdown presentation compiled with RStudio. Those knitr options doesnt seem to work :(

````
```{r, eval=FALSE,fig.width=100}
grid <- seq(0,1,0.00001)
L <- (factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))) * grid^k*(1-grid)^(n-k)
```
````

If I open the presentation, the code chunk above is splitted after "L <-". The rest of the code moves in the next line.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should add spaces in your code, so that your web browser can find a more reasonable position to break the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go a few ways. First you can use `width:#####` and `height:#####` in the frontmatter to specify a custom max height/width for your whole presentation.

You could also use a custom css file (e.g. `css: mypres.css`) where you modify the `.reveal pre` and `.reveal code .r` and (perhaps) the `.reveal .slides` CSS styles to fit your needs.

Smaller text == harder to read on a big screen. Wider box == might not fit well on a big screen.